# Button on click methods and conditions not getting called when defined from shared view models in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewmodel

I have 5 fragments and one parent fragment which takes care of the fragment navigation. All these fragments use a common (shared) view model to share data across all fragments. But when I try to call a method from XML on button's onClick, it doesn't get called. I added breakpoint but the debugger didn't stop there at all.
Moreover, I have some visibility conditions defined in the view which are also using viewmodel reference and those don't execute either.

Below is the code of button click

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/previousBTN"
        style="@style/buttonStyleWithFillColor"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/common_44"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/common_50"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/common_15"
        android:clickable="@{!viewModel.isHorizontalProgress()}"
        android:fontFamily="@font/lato_bold_style"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:onClick="@{()->viewModel.previous()}"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/common_20"
        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/common_20"
        android:text="@string/submit"
        android:visibility="@{viewModel.currentTabIndex==5? View.VISIBLE:View.GONE}"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />
```

In the above code, you can see a method call on button click and a visibility condition . None of them works.

`CurrentTabIndex` is a mutable live data defined in viewModel

```
    var currentTabIndex = MutableLiveData(1)
```

This is the viewModel class

```
class EmpGPViewModel @ViewModelInject constructor(application: Application): BaseViewModel<EmpGPNavigator>(application) {
var model=MutableLiveData<EmpGPModel>()
var currentTabIndex = MutableLiveData(1)
fun selectDate() {
    navigator.selectDate()
}
fun selectOutTime() {
    navigator.selectOutTime()
}
fun next() {
    navigator.next()
}

fun previous() {
    navigator.previous()
}

fun submit() {
    navigator.submit()
}}
```

I am also using Hilt in this project for dependency injection. I also have the same code setup on a different screen only difference is that it doesn't use a shared view model and there all of this code works.

I have a base fragment class which provides an overridden method to instantiate viewModel.
This is how I do it.

```
override val viewModel: EmpGPViewModel by viewModels()
```

Base fragment class has calls below code

```
 viewDataBinding?.lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner
    viewDataBinding?.setVariable(bindingVariable, mViewModel)
    viewDataBinding?.executePendingBindings()
```

Comment: How are you creating `ViewModel` in Fragment ? Also add code where u are setting VM to binding object

Comment: @ADM added code. I have a base fragment class and I inherit it my fragment class

Comment: I believe you are creating multiple viewmodels since you inherit the same class in different fragments but that will instantiate different object in each fragment. Try printing the memory reference or something to make sure that is a sharedviewmodel

Comment: By using `viewModels()`  you are not creating a shared VM . That will  be one VM instance fro each fragment . But your binding method should get called anyway if you are debugging it . that a problem .

Comment: @ADM how to create a shared one ?. Also the method that I am currently calling, are being called from main fragment so they should get called atleast. Or is it because fragment loaded creates a new reference for same view model ?

Comment: Not sure but something like this i guess `val viewModel: EmpGPViewModel by viewModels(ownerProducer = { requireParentFragment() })` .

Comment: @ADM do I have to this in child fragments or in the main fragment or both ?

Comment: Didn't worked . I may have missed one scenario is that my main fragment hosts a view pager and that viewpager then loads child fragments